# How to setup a VPN on a Fritzbox 6690 Cable without IPv4

Tags: router, vpn, ipv6, isp, fritzbox

So I have a Vodafone Contract and need to route all my traffic through a VPN.

Unfortunately they only provide IPv6 adresses and handle IPv4 trough DS-Lite.

I called with customer support and it's not possible to give out IPv4 addresses.

Can I somehow route all my IPv6 traffic through a VPN using WireGuard?

In the Fritzbox UI there's only a checkbox to route all IPv4 traffic through WireGuard.

I setup a Wireguard connection using DS-Lite and the Fritzbox shows it's connected but I still have the public IPv4 address of my ISP.

How can I setup a VPN tunnel when using Vodafone Cable as ISP?